# I'm new to Prolog and I don't know where I'm going wrong

Tags: prolog

```
Current predicate: wings/1
Warning:    Use :- discontiguous size/1. to suppress this message
Warning:    Clauses of bill/1 are not together in the source-file
Warning:    Current predicate: size/1
Warning:    Use :- discontiguous bill/1. to suppress this message
Warning:    Clauses of live/1 are not together in the source-file
Warning:    Current predicate: bill/1
Warning:    Use :- discontiguous live/1. to suppress this message
Warning:    Clauses of nostrils/1 are not together in the source-file
Warning:    Current predicate: live/1
```

This is the code I'm using.

```
:-dynamic known/3.
top_goal(X):-bird(X).
bird(laysan_albatross):-
  family(albatross),
  color(white).
bird(black_footed_albatross):-
  family(albatross),
  color(dark).
bird(whistling_swan):-
  family(swan),
  voice(muffled_musical_whistle).
bird(trumpeter_swan):-
  family(swan),
  voice(loud_trumpeting).
order(tubenose):-
 nostrils(external_tubular),
 live(at_sea),
 bill(hooked).
order(waterfowl):-
feet(webbed),
bill(flat).
family(albatross):-
order(tubenose),
size(large),
wings(long_narrow).
family(swan):-
order(waterfowl),
neck(long),
color(white),
flight(ponderous).
nostrils(external_tubular).
live(at_sea).
bill(hooked).
size(large).
wings(long_narrow).
color(dark).
color(X):-ask(color,X).
wings(X):-ask(wings,X).
size(X):-ask(size,X).
bill(X):-ask(bill,X).
live(X):-ask(live,X).
nostrils(X):-ask(nostrils,X).
voice(X):-ask(voice,X).
flight(X):-ask(flight,X).
feet(X):-ask(feet,X).
neck(X):-ask(neck,X).
ask(A, V):-
known(yes, A, V),
!.
ask(A, V):-
known(_, A, V),
!,fail.
ask(A, V):-
write(A:V),
write('? : '),
read(Y),
asserta(known(Y, A, V)),
Y==yes.
solve:-
retractall(known(_,_,_)),
top_goal(X),
write('The bird is'),write(X),nl.
solve:-
write('This is an unknown bird.'),nl.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting a full stop character where you should be using a comma in the swan family:

```
family(swan):-
    order(waterfowl),
    neck(long),
    color(white),
    flight(ponderous).                %Should be ',' instead of '.'
    nostrils(external_tubular).       %idem
    live(at_sea). bill(hooked). size(large). %idem
    wings(long_narrow).               %idem
    color(dark).                      %This full stop is ok
```

These characters are very different in purpose !
As per your code, you are defining bill/1 or live/1 after the swan family code, and again when you ask the user. So prolog sees that as two separate definitions of the same predicate, which it flagged as "discontinous" error.

Comment: Have I answered your question ? If so, upgrade this answer. If not, clarify your question or ask another question.